# What do equations involving infinitesimals say?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation, calculus, bernoulli-equation, navier-stokes

I am reading this [note](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-09-classical-mechanics-iii-fall-2014/3bfed6897483f5c55bf615ed583af603_MIT8_09F14_Chapter_6.pdf) on the Bernoulli equations with the following derivations:

[image]

I am struggling to find a calculus based meaning for the above equations involving the infinitesimal $\delta V$: I tried replacing $\delta V$ with differential form, but $\delta V$ doesn't behave like $dV$, the volume element because $\frac{d}{dt}(\rho dV)\neq 0$; I am trying to replace $\delta V$ with $\int_{\delta V}$, basically summing the quantity $\delta V$ is concatenated with over a small drop of liquid $\delta V$, but this brings the problem of how to show $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2\delta V)=\delta V\rho v\cdot\frac{dv}{dt}$ given $\frac{d}{dt}(\rho\delta V)$.

Could people help me with understanding these equations involving $\delta V$s?

Comment: You can formalize it with big/little-o notation. Simpler example: by $(V+\delta V)^2-V^2=2V\delta V$ we mean these expressions  differ by something $o(\delta V)$.

Comment: Could it be something like the first variation? ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation )

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.